# Why Is Firemonkey TMemo Borderless

Tags: firemonkey

Is there a way to provide a border for the memo box?  I am currently putting the memo in a rectangle to give it a border and setting each of the memo margins to 1.  I hate that I have to use this workaround.  Using XE6 and XE7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only updating style for **TMemo** or use your workaround with **TRectangle**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```pascal
procedure TVariableHeight.Memo1Paint(Sender: TObject; Canvas: TCanvas;
  const ARect: TRectF);
begin
  if Canvas.BeginScene then
  begin
    with Canvas do
    begin
      Fill.Color := TAlphaColorRec.White;
      FillRect(RectF(0, 0, Memo1.Width, 1), 0, 0, AllCorners, 1);
      FillRect(RectF(0, 0, 1, Memo1.Height), 0, 0, AllCorners, 1);
      FillRect(RectF(Memo1.Width, 0, Memo1.Width - 1, Memo1.Height), 0, 0,
        AllCorners, 1);
      FillRect(RectF(0, Memo1.Height, Memo1.Width, Memo1.Height - 1), 0, 0,
        AllCorners, 1);
    end;
    Canvas.EndScene;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Nice effort in typing up the code.  It would be even more helpful if you were to explain the intent/idea behind it.